# Exponential martingale is closed iff $\mathbb{E}M_{\sigma_a}=1$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I am working on Exercise 3.28 of Jean-François Le Gall's *Brownian Motion, Martingales and Stochastic Calculus*. I want to prove the following fact (which is part of Question 3):

> Let $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a complete filtration and $B$ be an $(\mathcal{F}_t)$-Brownian motion. Let $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $M_t=\exp\left(\mu B_t-\mu^2 t/2\right)$. The stopped martingale $(M_{t\land\sigma_a})_{t\geq 0}$ is closed if and only if $\mathbb{E}M_{\sigma_a}=1$ where $\sigma_a$ is the stopping time $\inf\left\{t\geq 0: B_t\leq t-a\right\}$, with $a>0$.

The implication is trivial. For the converse, by the optional stopping theorem for nonnegative supermatingales,
$$\forall t\geq 0, \text{ a.s.}, \quad M_{\sigma\land t}\geq\mathbb{E}\left[M_{\sigma_a}\mid\mathcal{F}_{\sigma_a\land t}\right]\equiv Z_t$$
Reasoning by contradiction, I am able to show that
$$\forall t\geq 0, \text{ a.s.}, \quad M_{\sigma_a\land t}=Z_t$$
So $(Z_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a modification of $\left(M_{\sigma_a\land t}\right)_{t\geq 0}$. My questions are the following

1. To show that the stopped martingale is closed, this is not enough, correct? I need to show that the two processes are indistinguishable?
2. I know that if both processes are continuous, then they are indistinguishable. However, I don't know how to show continuity...

Do you have ideas on how to do this (or, if this is the wrong method, how to tackle Question 3)?

Comment: Assuming the filtration to be right continuous, you can resolve (some of) the ambiguity in the choice of each $Z_t$ by taking $t\mapsto Z_t$ to be right continuous, a.s. This $(Z_t)$ is then indistinguishable from $(M_{\sigma_a\wedge t})$.

Comment: Is the reasoning the following: if the filtration is right-continuous and complete, since $Z$ is a martingale, there is a modification of $Z$ with càdlàg sample paths which is also a martingale for the filtration (Theorem 3.18 in Le Gall's book)?

Comment: Yes, that's it precisely.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks a lot. Is it always necessary to prove indistinguishability in these cases or is a modification enough? Also, I would be very happy to accept your answer if you posted something!

Comment: In the present situation, by the reasoning you outlined, it is necessary to show indistinguishability. Whether "modification" would suffice depends on the situation. Modifications have the same finite-dimensional distributions, but may not have the same path properties.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Awesome! Thank you so much, it's all much clearer now :)